# ALLDOCUBE kPad Magisk

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, fastboot, magisk

Before you ask, I cannot use TWRP or any custom recovery since I couldn't find any for my device.

I have spend over a day trying to flash Magisk on my kPad I got for Prime Day. Every single time, it's been bootloop after bootloop after bootloop in flashing either slot A or B. I couldn't flash vbmeta since there were 5 different vbmeta files and none of them said vbmeta standalone. At this point, I'm about to give up and seeking help online is my last resort.

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me.